# com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.1.1 ERROR

Tags: android, firebase

After running Application i get this error.

```
    Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.3.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio1/gradle/m2repository/com/twitter/sdk/android/twitter/2.3.0/twitter-2.3.0.pom
         file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio1/gradle/m2repository/com/twitter/sdk/android/twitter/2.3.0/twitter-2.3.0.jar
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/twitter/sdk/android/twitter/2.3.0/twitter-2.3.0.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/twitter/sdk/android/twitter/2.3.0/twitter-2.3.0.jar
         file:/C:/Users/------/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/twitter/sdk/android/twitter/2.3.0/twitter-2.3.0.pom
         file:/C:/Users/-----ppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/twitter/sdk/android/twitter/2.3.0/twitter-2.3.0.jar
         file:/C:/Users/----/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/twitter/sdk/android/twitter/2.3.0/twitter-2.3.0.pom
         file:/C:/Users/------/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/twitter/sdk/android/twitter/2.3.0/twitter-2.3.0.jar
     Required by:
         MYAPP:app:unspecified > com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.1.1
```

MY build gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled false
    }
    buildTypes {
//        debug {
//            minifyEnabled true
//            useProguard false
//            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
//        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/fonts'] } }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    // FirebaseUI Database only
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.1.1'

    // FirebaseUI Auth only
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.1.1'

    // FirebaseUI Storage only
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.1.1'

    // Single target that includes all FirebaseUI libraries above
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

::

```
  // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()

        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files

        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()

        }

    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

Have been trying to fix this from days no idea what might be issue, Anyone it would be grateful if one can take a look.
Also was wondering if i lower the firebase ui or sometging will that help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your top-level (project) build.gradle to contain this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
}
```

The need for the maven repository is [noted in the documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md).

To resolve the manifest merge problem you added in your comment, update your `AndroidManifest.xml` file to include the tools namespace:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.your.app.package"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

And then add the override for `supportsRTL`:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    tools:replace="android:supportsRtl"
```

This issue is [discussed here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/520).

Comment: i got error:  'Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@supportsRtl value=(true) from AndroidManifest.xml:17:9-35
 is also present at [com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.1.1] AndroidManifest.xml:14:18-45 value=(false).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:supportsRtl"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:13:5-212:19 to override.'

Comment: I haven't seen that before.  Did you try the solution suggested in the error message?

Comment: To be honest i not really sure whats it saying @qbix

Comment: The issue is [discussed here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/520).  I'll update my answer shortly.

Comment: Ok Thanks,awaiting

Answer (score 0):

Some solutions claims that you have to put this:

```
repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
```

just above the dependencies in build.gradle inside the app folder and it will solve the above mentioned issue